# "The L2TP-VPN server did not respond" on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, network, security, vpn

I have a problem with VPN connection on OS X Yosemite
I imported certificates, set them "Always trust" policy and created connection (I set User authentication: Password, Machine authentication: Certificate in "Authentication settings..." dialog). However when I try to connect, I get "The L2TP-VPN server did not respond" error message.

here what I get in /etc/log/ppp.log file:

```
Thu Apr 23 21:31:30 2015 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Thu Apr 23 21:31:30 2015 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Thu Apr 23 21:31:41 2015 : l2tp_get_router_address  
Thu Apr 23 21:31:41 2015 : l2tp_get_router_address 192.168.1.1 from dict 1  
Thu Apr 23 21:31:41 2015 : L2TP connecting to server '<site>' (<ip address>)...  
Thu Apr 23 21:31:41 2015 : IPSec connection started  
Thu Apr 23 21:31:41 2015 : IPSec phase 1 client started  
Thu Apr 23 21:31:41 2015 : IPSec phase 1 server replied  
Thu Apr 23 21:31:42 2015 : IPSec connection failed <IKE Error 22 (0x16) Invalid cert authority>
```

What can cause that? Is there a way to get more detailed information?
* Same certificates work fine on Windows virtual machine.